# Oracle, Spring JDBC, the fastest way how to delete data from table

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc

I use JdbcTemplate's batchUpdate to insert big amount of data into db tables

What is the fastest way to delete it?

I use

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ID >= MIN_ID
```

where **MIN_ID** is the startValue of the sequence = 1000000

Note, I want to start from MIN_ID and keep data with IDs below 1000000

Is there better approach?
What best practices should one follow?

Note, I use Oracle db

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the entire table since MIN_ID is the startValue, you can use [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm) as `TRUNCATE TABLE tableName;`

Comment: The thing is MIN_ID, startValue = 1000000, there can be some test data which I don't want to delete. I want to start from MIN_ID

Comment: If the data is just for your session, you can just insert it without commit-ing it and after you are done with your test, you can issue a rollback

Comment: No, that's not the case. I have the oracle db with some pre-existing data, I want to insert huge amounts and then clean-up

Comment: In that case, if the machine that runs your database has some CPU resources available, you can use the [PARALLEL hint](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_parallel_hint.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete big part of table it is usually cheaper to `create new_table as select * from tableName where nvl(ID,-1) < MIN_ID;` and swap names. Don't forget about swaping indexes and recreating constraints and other objects. Of course if someone can insert the table during process of swapping you need either lock table or implement some consistency mechanism that will take care of data inserted during swap.